# Need to save two tables from different jsp pages with foreign key relationship using hibernate dao implementation method

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp

**Image of table relationship reference**

[image: Image of table relationship reference]

---

**After submit from bank jsp page and after submit from card jsp all in one image because of limitation of newbie**
[image: After submit from bank jsp page and after submit from card jsp all in one image because of limitation of newbie]

---

I am new to stackoverflow as well `SPRING`. I have tried to create two tables with foreign key concept . I have followed some examples on stackoverflow as well as from other resourcefull websites and manged to create two tables with onetomany relationship. But the problem is i have to get the first row id under cart_id column when i submit from card jsp page. Instead after submit from card jsp page there is new row created under bankadmin table and it's id is being returned. I am confused and have no idea how to correct ot resolve this issue. Please  be kind and guide me. And also i have been searching for a week in stackoverflow couldn't find anything that helped me. Thanks in advance.

---

## **Bankadmin Model**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "bankAdmin")
    public class bankAdmin implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "bcode", nullable=false)
    @Id private int bcode;

    @Column (name = "bname")
    private String bname;

    @Column (name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column (name = "phno")
    private int phno;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bankAdmin",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Cards> cards;
```

### **Card model**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "cards")
    public class Cards implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cname", unique=true)
    @Id private int cname;

    @Column (name = "ctype")
    private String ctype;

    @Column (name = "min_sal")
    private int min_sal;

    @Column (name = "year_fee")
    private int year_fee;

    @Column (name = "rewards")
    private String rewards;

    @Column (name = "jperks")
    private String jperks;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    private bankAdmin bankAdmin;
    public Cards(){}

    public Cards(String ctype, int min_sal, int year_fee, String rewards, String jperks, bankAdmin b){//int cname, 
        this.ctype=ctype;
        this.min_sal=min_sal;
        this.year_fee=year_fee;
        this.jperks=jperks;
        this.rewards=rewards;
        this.bankAdmin=b;
    } 

    public bankAdmin getBankAdmin() {
        return bankAdmin;
    }
    public void setBankAdmin(bankAdmin bankAdmin) {
        this.bankAdmin = bankAdmin;
    }
```

---

### **CardDaoImpl**

```
    public class CardsDaoImpl implements CardsDao{

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    public void save(Cards cards) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try 
        {
            session = this.sessionfactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            bankAdmin bankadmin =new bankAdmin(); //=null;
            String _ctype = cards.getctype();
            int _min_sal = cards.getmin_sal();
            int _year_fee = cards.getyear_fee();
            String _rewards = cards.getrewards();
            String _jperks = cards.getjperks();
            Set<Cards> card = new HashSet<Cards>();
            Cards config =  new Cards(_ctype,_min_sal,_year_fee,_rewards,_jperks,bankadmin);
            card.add(config);
            bankadmin.setcards(card);
//          System.out.println("bankadmin: before " + bankadmin);
//          bankadmin.setbname(bankadmin.getbname());// "SBI"
//          bankadmin.setphno(bankadmin.getphno());//1234567890
//          bankadmin.setaddress(bankadmin.getaddress());//Bengaluru
//          System.out.println("bankadmin: after " + bankadmin);

//          int _cname = cards.getcname();

//          int bankadmin = bankadmin.getbcode();

            //_cname,_ctype,_min_sal,_year_fee,_rewards,_jperks,bankadmin
//          card.add(config);
//          config.setBankAdmin(cards.getBankAdmin(bankadmin));

//          config.setcname(cards.getcname());
//          config.setctype(cards.getctype());
//          config.setmin_sal(cards.getmin_sal());
//          config.setyear_fee(cards.getyear_fee());
//          config.setrewards(cards.getrewards());
//          config.setjperks(cards.getjperks());
//          config.setBankAdmin(cards.getBankAdmin());
            session.save(bankadmin);
            session.save(config);
            tx.commit();
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

//  get lms lights config from DB
    public List<Cards> Ccards() {
        Session session = null;
//      Transaction tx = null;
        List<Cards> Ccards = null;

        try{
            session = this.sessionfactory.openSession();
            Ccards = session.createQuery("FROM Cards").list();
            System.out.println("cards dao impl executed...");
            System.out.println("cards config : "+ Ccards.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("bankAdmin Dao impl Ex : " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }

        return Ccards;
    }



}
```

---

**BankDaoImpl**

---

```
    public class bankAdminDaoImpl implements bankAdminDao{
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    public void save(bankAdmin badmin) {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;

        try 
        {   
            session = this.sessionfactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
//          bankAdmin bankadmin = new bankAdmin();
            bankAdmin config =  new bankAdmin();
            config.setbcode(badmin.getbcode());
            config.setbname(badmin.getbname());
            config.setaddress(badmin.getaddress());
            config.setphno(badmin.getphno());

            session.save(config);//save//persist
            tx.commit();
        } 
        catch (HibernateException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally 
        {
            session.close();
        }
    }

//  get lms lights config from DB
    public List<bankAdmin> BbankAdmin() {
        Session session = null;
//      Transaction tx = null;
        List<bankAdmin> BbankAdmin = null;

        try{
            session = this.sessionfactory.openSession();
            BbankAdmin = session.createQuery("FROM bankAdmin").list();
            System.out.println("bankAdmin dao impl executed...");
            System.out.println("bankAdmin config : "+ BbankAdmin.toString());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("bankAdmin Dao impl Ex : " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            session.close();
        }

        return BbankAdmin;
    }


}
```

Comment: I would love to help you, but I do not have time now so I will return later. You are getting an empty entry in your bank database with id 2 because you are creating a new `bankAdmin` in `CardDaoImpl.save()`. You are creating this object with no properites which is why it is empty in your database. What you would want to do is find the bank with id 1, create a new card and associate those two objects afterwards and then save the object.

Comment: Can you please post a SQL dump of the database structure?

Comment: @kkflf , i honestly don't know how to dump the database structure as i am using windows 10. All the examples are related to Linux shell. And regarding that association of two objects, how can i find the bank with id 1? Since that is related to a class "bankAdmin bankadmin" , query cannot be cast to bankAdmin . Also if i use Query separately , then bankadmin won't be mapped to this   Query. I have been trying very hard.

Comment: Install mysql workbench. You can create a database dump of the structure there. That is the easiest approach unless you got mysql binary files accessible from cmd or powershell. Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bankadmin`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bankadmin` (
  `bcode` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phno` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;       @kkflf

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cards`;
CREATE TABLE `cards` (
  `cname` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ctype` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jperks` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_sal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rewards` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year_fee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cart_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cname`),
  KEY `FK_7656159a27eb41cebe38c4029ea` (`cart_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7656159a27eb41cebe38c4029ea` FOREIGN KEY (`cart_id`) REFERENCES `bankadmin` (`bcode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; @kkflf

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it. How have you setup your datasource for spring? Application.properties or a datasource in java?

Comment: Those properties are under src/main/java/resources/DB.Properties (/crdmng/src/main/java/resources/DB.properties).

Comment: I have added an solution for you. I really hope it will help you overcome your troubles. I have made sure that the code can compile and run correct. Please feel free to ask question if something is not clear. My answer was typed quickly.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @kkflf, Still working on it. So much of tables to change. It will take the entire day for me. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @kkflf,  
can i Autowire the Webpage controller to the CardDao? I am trying your suggestion above . i was busy with college exams. Also i am using service implementation "CardServiceImpl".

Comment: @kkflf ,Also i have two different jsp pages. I have to get those adress, phno etc from the input box. I am having trouble working with and your  CardDao. Please help. Do i have to share my project structure. If yes , i Will share. This project is not bootstrap, it is maven web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I have posted the solution to your problem.

First of all, Spring framework is wonderful to work with. The framework got a lot of features, that you should take advantage of. I am not sure if I will be able to cover everything in this post, so please feel free to ask me.

I have created a simple Spring Boot application. I got total of 6 files that are important which is posted below.

Notice that I renamed your classes to CamelCase with capital starting letter. such as `BankAdmin`. This is considered the standard way of writing java classes. Also note that i renamed `Cards` to `Card`, so remember to rename your table in the database aswell. Also remember to rename the bankadmin table to bank_admin.

There are thee annotations that you have to look into. `@Transactional`, `@Autowired`, and `PersistenceContext`.

So a quick and easy explanation. `@Transactional` manages all transactions for you, so you do not have to begin and commit transactions. `@Autowired` creates objects for you, so you do not have to manage your object dependencies yourself. `PersistenceContext` basically creates and EntityManager for you and manages it for you. You do not have to create session nor EntitManagerFactory. These three annotations are explained very brief, so you should read about them yourself.

I also removed `@Table(name = "bankAdmin")` and `@Table(name = "cards")`. JPA can lookup these tables automatically if you follow the standard way of naming classes and database tables. It is actually pretty simple, but I still encourage you to look into this by yourself. In short, capital camelcase is turned into lowercase with `_` inbetween each word that start with a capital letter. I.e. If your class name is `BankAdmin` then JPA will automatically look for table named `bank_admin` in your database.

**application.properties - details about your database**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**The below code is only written to test the functionality**

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class StackoverflowApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);

        //Calling a class that is only made with the purpose of testing
        Verification ts = ctx.getBean(Verification.class);
        ts.run();
    }
    }

    @Component
    class Verification{

    @Autowired
    private BankAdminDao bad;

    @Autowired
    private CardsDao cd;

    void run(){
        //Create a new BankAdmin
        BankAdmin ba = new BankAdmin();
        ba.setAddress("someStreet");
        ba.setPhno(12341234);
        ba.setBname("myBanker");

        //Create two cards and add them to a HashSet.
        Card c1 = new Card("Visa", 1000, 1999, "Alot of", "Babes", ba);
        Card c2 = new Card("Master Card", 2000, 500, "someThing", "anotherThing", ba);
        Set<Card> cardList = new HashSet<>();
        cardList.add(c1);
        cardList.add(c2);

        //Create a associatio between the BankAdmin and list of Cards
        ba.setCards(cardList);

        //Save them to the database.
        bad.save(ba);

        //Here we add a Card to an existing BankAdmin with the id 6 in the database.

        //Create a new Card.
        //The BankAdmin is set to null, because we not have not yet loaded the BankAdmin
        Card c3 = new Card("Visa", 9999, 1337, "Alot of", "Male Babes", null);

        //Save Card c3 with the BankAdmin id 6
        cd.save(c3, 6);

    }
    }
```

**BankAdmin**

```
    @Entity
    public class BankAdmin implements Serializable{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column (name = "bcode", nullable=false)
    @Id private int bcode;

    @Column (name = "bname")
    private String bname;

    @Column (name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column (name = "phno")
    private int phno;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bankAdmin",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Card> cards;

    //Getters and Setters have been removed to reduce the amount of code.
    }
```

**BankAdminDao**

```
    @Repository
    //Transactional makes transaction automatical, so you do not have to begin and commit transactions yourself!
    @Transactional 
    public class BankAdminDao{

    //This makes your life a lot eaier!
    //It will take care of your EntitManagerFactory and Sessions
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void save(BankAdmin bank) {
        em.merge(bank);
    }

    //get lms lights config from DB
    public List<BankAdmin> getAllBankAdmin() {
         List<BankAdmin> bankList = (List<BankAdmin>)em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM BankAdmin b");
         return bankList;
    }

    public BankAdmin getBankAdmin(int bankId) {
        return em.find(BankAdmin.class, bankId);
    }
    }
```

**Card**

```
    @Entity
    public class Card implements Serializable {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="cname", unique=true)
    @Id private int cname;

    @Column (name = "ctype")
    private String ctype;

    @Column (name = "min_sal")
    private int min_sal;

    @Column (name = "year_fee")
    private int year_fee;

    @Column (name = "rewards")
    private String rewards;

    @Column (name = "jperks")
    private String jperks;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", nullable=false)
    private BankAdmin bankAdmin;

    public Card(){}

    public Card(String ctype, int min_sal, int year_fee, String rewards, String jperks, BankAdmin b){
        this.ctype=ctype;
        this.min_sal=min_sal;
        this.year_fee=year_fee;
        this.jperks=jperks;
        this.rewards=rewards;
        this.bankAdmin=b;
    } 

    public BankAdmin getBankAdmin() {
        return bankAdmin;
    }
    public void setBankAdmin(BankAdmin bankAdmin) {
        this.bankAdmin = bankAdmin;
    }
    }
```

**CardDao**

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class CardsDao{

        @PersistenceContext
        EntityManager em;

        @Autowired
        BankAdminDao bad;

        public void save(Card cards, int bankId) {
            BankAdmin bank = bad.getBankAdmin(bankId);
            cards.setBankAdmin(bank);   
            bank.getCards().add(cards);
            em.merge(bank);
        }

        public List<Card> getAllCards() {
            List<Card> cardList = (List<Card>)em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Cards c");
             return cardList;
        }

        public Card getCard(int cardId){
            return em.find(Card.class, cardId);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can i Autowire the Webpage controller to the CardDao? I am trying your suggestion above . i was busy with college exams. Also i am using service implementation "CardServiceImpl".

Comment: After spending a long time in front of my laptop, I have successfully solved my problem. Thank you. And I did not use entity manager , I use sessionfactory and used your method under DAO as well SERVICE accordingly it worked!.

Comment: Good to hear! You should really consider using entitymanager. It is standard component of JPA. Sessionsmanger is hibernate specific. I am glad to hear that you solved your problem. Rock on!